# Asymptotic behavior of the sequence $a_{n+1}=f(a_n)$ where $f(x)=\frac{x}{1+\sqrt{x}}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

### The sequence and basic asymptotic behavior

Here is  a sequence defined by iterations: $f(x)=\frac{x}{1+\sqrt{x}}$ and $a_1=1$, $a_{n+1}=f(a_n)$ for $n=1,2,3,\cdots$. Then I can prove that $n^2a_n\to 4$ as $n \to \infty$.

### Prove details

With Taylor series of $\frac{1}{1+x}$ we can derive
$$
\begin{aligned}
&f(x)\\
=&\sqrt{x}-1+\frac{1}{1+\sqrt x}\\
=&\sqrt x-1+1-\sqrt x+x-x^{3/2}+\cdots\\
=&x-x^{3/2}+x^2+o(x^2)
\end{aligned}
$$
So
$$
a_{n+1}=a_n-a_n^{3/2}+a_n^2+o(a_n^2)
$$
For sake of using **Stolz Theorem**:
$$
\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{a_n}{b_n}=\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{a_{n+1}-a_n}{b_{n+1}-b_n}
$$
Consider:
$$
\begin{aligned}
&\sqrt{a_{n+1}}=\sqrt{a_n-a_n^{3/2}+a_n^2+o(a_n^2)}\\
=&\sqrt{a_n}\sqrt{1-\sqrt{a_n}+a_n+o(a_n)}\\
=&\sqrt{a_n}(1-\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{a_n}+o(\sqrt a_n))\\
=&\sqrt a_n-\frac{1}{2}a_n+o(a_n)
\end{aligned}
$$
So
$$
\begin{aligned}
&\lim_{n\to \infty} n\sqrt{a_n}\\
(\mathrm{Stolz})=&\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{n+1-n}{a_{n+1}^{-1/2}-a_n^{-1/2}}\\
=&\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{\sqrt{a_{n+1}a_n}}{\sqrt{a_n}-\sqrt{a_{n+1}}}\\
(\mathrm{Substitute}\quad a_{n+1})=&\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{\sqrt a_n (\sqrt a_n-\frac{1}{2}a_n+o(\sqrt a_n))}{\frac{1}{2}a_n+o(a_n)}\\
=&\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{a_n-\frac{1}{2}a_n^{3/2}+o(a_n)}{\frac{1}{2}a_n+o(a_n)}\\
=&2
\end{aligned}
$$

### My question

Since
$$
a_n\sim \frac{4}{n^2}
$$
We know
$$
S=\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n
$$
is convergent（because $\sum_{n=1}^\infty n^{-2}=\pi^2/6$  is convergent）.

And I calculate a estimation of S use python：

```
from math import *

f = lambda x:x/(1+sqrt(x))

def g(n):
    if n==1:
        return f(1)
    else:
        return f(g(n-1))

sum([g(i) for i in range(1,1000)])
```

The return value is `1.809401237424014`, quite close to $\pi^2/6=1.6449340668482264$

But how can I get the **TRUE value of S** ?

---

### Update of python code

Use iteration instead of recursion：
(and add up $a_1=1$ which is missed in firt edition code.)

```
from math import *

f = lambda x:x/(1+sqrt(x))

print('n\t a_n*n^2 \t S_n')

for n in [10,100,1_000,10_000,100_000,1_000_000,10_000_000]:
    a,b = 1, f(1)
    s = 0
    for i in range(1,n+1):
        s += a
        a,b = b, f(b)
    print(i,a*i**2,s)
```

The output is:

```
n        a_n*n^2         S_n
10 3.2204912056418102 2.4298826498260837  
100 3.996200298802558 2.7731272874933808  
1000 4.0088383879232925 2.8094012374240087
10000 4.001804372268226 2.813008541254141 
100000 4.000272501187805 2.8133686598142846
1000000 4.000036459434159 2.8134046614556216
10000000 4.000004566957753 2.8134082614756544
```

BTW maybe the **TRUE value of S** is just a trivial irrational like $e$ when it's not named.

Comment: than u for the edition

Comment: $S$ does not converge to $\frac{\pi^2}{6}$ because  $a_n \sim \frac{4}{n^2}$ only for $n$ sufficiently large.

Comment: Yeah, So I wonder the true value of S. I mentioned$\pi^2/6$because S is close to it.

Comment: @onsdriver I would not call that close. It is much closer to $9/5$ for instance.

Comment: Also since you sum up only $1000$ terms and $a_n \sim 4n^{-2}$, you obtain about $2$ correct digits of the true value of $S$. In fact, $$
\sum\limits_{n = N + 1}^\infty  {a_n }  = \frac{4}{N} + \frac{{2\log N}}{{N^2 }} + \mathcal{O}\!\left( {\frac{1}{{N^2 }}} \right).
$$

Comment: With this approximation $S=2.8134086607\ldots$ up to $10$ decimal places.

Comment: @Gary. derivatives of $\zeta$ function, may be.

Answer (score 0):

I do not understand the numbers. I type the formulae I used (just in case)
$$f(x)=\frac{x}{1+\sqrt{x}}\qquad a_1=1 \qquad a_n=f(a_{n-1})\qquad S_p=\sum_{n=1}^p a_n$$

First of all, $b_n=n^2\,a_n$  is not asymptotic to $4$ but a bit higher (this statement is **wrong** I missed the maximum value)

Concerning the summation, I have the same number for $n=1000$ (you forgot to count $a_1$ in the sum).

Computing much more terms

$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
k   &   S_{10^k} \\
3   &   2.8094012374240087  \\  
4   &   2.8130085412541410  \\
5   &   2.8133686598142846  \\
6   &   2.8134046614556216  \\
7   &   2.8134082614756544  \\
8   &   2.8134086207865772  \\   
\end{array}
\right)$$

This number is not recognized by the inverse symbolic calculators I used.

Comment: The OP is right. In fact $$
a_n  = \frac{4}{{n^2 }}\left( {1 + \frac{{\log n}}{n} + \mathcal{O}\!\left( {\frac{1}{n}} \right)} \right)
$$ as $n\to +\infty$. This follows from [this paper](https://www.emis.de/journals/AMEN/2013/130218(final).pdf).

Comment: I am sorry I made a mistake in coding!

Comment: @Gary. Your statement is correct : I missed the fact that $b_n$ goes through at maximum value